# Are there any other examples of using F-algebras in interesting categories to describe computer science constructions?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science

Algebraic Subtyping$^1$ presents types as an initial algebra in the category of distributive lattices. This informs the design of the type inference algorithm and various correctness properties.

In the Nominal Sets literature$^2$, an initial algebra in the category of nominal sets is used to create datatypes that allow recursion modulo alpha equivalence.

Are there any other examples of initial algebra semantics in categories other than Set that help accomplish computational goals?

[$^1$]: Dolan, S. (2017). Algebraic Subtyping. BCS, The Chartered Institute for IT.

[$^2$]: Pitts, A. (2016). Nominal techniques. ACM SIGLOG News, 3(1), 57-72.

Comment: The first example that comes to mind is that an inductive type can be interpreted by an initial algebra of an endofunctor.

Comment: @Dave Non-indexed inductive types (like in ML) fall into the 'uninteresting' category of Set. But I would wouldn't be surprised if indexed types/inductive families have initial algebra semantics in a category with more structure.